# Trying to put if condion in r and creating a new variable with certain condition on two variables

Tags: sql, r, if-statement, plsql, sqldf

```
Group A      Group B
custid       sd,custid,region-101%41,townsize
region       region
townsize     townsize
gender       gender,(part2)
age          agecat,birthmonth,gendor
agecat       birthmonth
birthmonth   edcat
```

The SQL:

```
Select *,
       case when (GroupA=GROUPB) "OK"
            WHEN INSTR(GROUPA,GROUPB,1,1)>0 
                 and INSTR(GROUPA,GROUPB,',',1,1)>0"Ok but different groups"
       ELSE Review group "review);
```

The above code is working fine when trying to import data from oracle database.

I want to use same condition on r after creating a dataset in r language but it is not working,I tried sqldf package but still it is not working

```
Group A      Group B
custid       sd,custid,region-101%41,townsize
region       region
townsize     townsize
gender       gender,(part2)
age          agecat,birthmonth,gendor
agecat       birthmonth
birthmonth   edcat
```

[image]

If you could please help to write this query in R or sql .

Comment: I am not aware of a five-input parameter version of `INSTR` in Oracle.  Can you explain your code?  Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: `INSTR(GROUPA,GROUPB,',',1,1)` <-- what does this mean?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. (INSTR(GROUPA,GROUPB,',',1,1)>0)  I am not sure as I am trying to convert it in R language.I guess it means if above condition is true and there is also a comma in the string THEN print "OK but with multiple groups".

Comment: Don't leave us guessing; please add sample data to your question.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen.I apologize as I am new to the blog.I have added the sample image of the data

Comment: I don't speak R, but your statement saying "The above code is working fine" isn't true, as this code wouldn't compile in Oracle.

Comment: Your image link is not acceptable/satisfactory, as it could break later on, leaving your question not usable to anyone else.  Please include the sample data directly in your question.

Comment: @Littlefoot There isn't much R happening here, as `sqldf()` just executes a SQL statement.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen I have added the data if you could please take a look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments under the question I am assuming you want to use sqldf with the default SQLite backend for this.  In that case this corrects the errors in the `select`.
We assume the data in the Note at the end (shown in a reproducible manner).

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select *,
         case when GroupA = GroupB then 'OK'
              when instr(',' || GroupB || ',', ',' || GroupA || ',')
                 then 'OK but different groups'
              else 'review'
         end status
       from DF")
```

giving:

```
      GroupA                           GroupB                  status
1     custid sd,custid,region-101%41,townsize OK but different groups
2     region                           region                      OK
3   townsize                         townsize                      OK
4     gender                   gender,(part2) OK but different groups
5        age         agecat,birthmonth,gendor                  review
6     agecat                       birthmonth                  review
7 birthmonth                            edcat                  review
```

This could alternately be done with the `case_when` function in the dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
  mutate(status = case_when(
    GroupA == GroupB ~ "OK",
    mapply(grepl, paste0(',', GroupA, ','), paste0(',', GroupB, ',')) ~ 
      "OK but different groups",
    TRUE ~ 'review'
  ))
```

### Note

The input data in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- 'GroupA      GroupB
custid       sd,custid,region-101%41,townsize
region       region
townsize     townsize
gender       gender,(part2)
age          agecat,birthmonth,gendor
agecat       birthmonth
birthmonth   edcat'
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi it is working fine for most of the observation however in 400 obs out of 2000 condition is not matching. It should be with different groups but it is showing revie.

Comment: It works in the data you provided so you will need to provide a reproducible example.